# Trying to loop and multiply percentage per count line

Tags: c#

I can't figure out how to get the daily increase value and multiply that to each new count line. I'm pretty sure my error is in the math and trying to setup the calculations to output into the listbox.

```
if (numDays >= 0)
{

    // Continue to process the input. /

    // The following loop calculates the final distance traveled. /
    while (count <= numDays)
    {
        // Calculate the organism population. /
        avgIncreaseDecimal = avgIncreaseInputValue / 100;
        percentageCalc = (organismsInputValue * avgIncreaseDecimal);
        nextPopulationCalc = organismsInputValue + (organismsInputValue * avgIncreaseDecimal);

        // Display the orgamism population for each day. /
        organismsCalcListBox.Items.Add("After day " + count + ", the organism population is approx. " + nextPopulationCalc.ToString("n6"));

        // Add one to the loop counter. /
        count = count + 1;

        // Return focus back to the organisms TextBox. /
        organismsInputTextBox.Focus();
    }
}
```

I've studied other examples online... but I still don't get how to multiply 30% and add it to each new count line.

Comment: If you want 100% plus an additional 30% of a number you multiply it by 1.30.

Comment: we do not know the type of your variables. please include as much code as is required to run it. i can also not see anything about 30 percent or `0.3`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that avgIncreadeInputValue is a value 1-100 (percent) , oh and good luck with the rest of this school exercise you know asking others is a bit of cheating ;)

```
var   avgIncreaseDecimal = 1 + (avgIncreaseInputValue / 100); 
var nextPopulationCalc = organismsInputValue;

// The following loop calculates the final distance traveled. /
while (count <= numDays)
{
    // Calculate the organism population. /
    nextPopulationCalc = nextPopulationCalc * avgIncreaseDecimal;

    // Display the orgamism population for each day. /
    organismsCalcListBox.Items.Add("After day " + count + ", the organism population is approx. " + nextPopulationCalc.ToString("n6"));

    // Add one to the loop counter. /
    count = count + 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty tired now... but I'm trying to build a loop and for whatever number is input for average increase... i need to multiply that to the each new number/count line ... so if my percentage is 30... i need to multiply each new total by 30%... so the number grows by 30% each time... and then output each new result into a listbox.

Comment: yes that is what the code I gave you do, nextPopulationCalc contains the new calculated value for each iteration and then increases it the next round with the given increase number